# How to change the name/string of an item in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

After adding items this way:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 50; x++)
   {
      listBox1.Items.Add("Item " + x.ToString());
   }
```

I'm wondering how I can update their name later when changes are made. In the code. Let's suppose I want to change the name of the item at index 5, how do I do that?

Obviously something like that won't work:

```
listBox1.Items[5].???? = "new string";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following:

```
private void UpdateListBoxItem(ListBox lb, object item) {
        int index = lb.Items.IndexOf(item);
        int currIndex = lb.SelectedIndex;
        lb.BeginUpdate();
        try {
            lb.ClearSelected();
            lb.Items[index] = item;
            lb.SelectedIndex = currIndex;
        }
        finally {
            lb.EndUpdate();
        }
    }
```

And this is the usage:

```
MyObject item = (MyObject)myListBox.Items[0];
item.Text = "New value";
UpdateListBoxItem(myListBox, item);
```

Comment: This is `Over Kill` i guess

Comment: What is the point of finding the object from the index, then passing it to the function which finds the index back from the passed object and store the selected index and then update via index and then re-selecting the old item back? OP's question is much simpler than all that!

Answer (score 4):

Just

```
listBox1.Items[5] = "new string";
```

The `ListBox.ObjectCollection` is a collection of items which implements `IList`. Indexing which will give the item itself. So you can directly assign it.

Comment: Hm, I was certain it was the first thing I tried... I will try again and see if there was something I didn't type correctly the first time. Thanks!